# Get: TypeError: 'dict_values' object does not support indexing when using python 3.2.3

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my code:

```
{names[i]:d.values()[i] for i in range(len(names))}
```

This works completely fine when using python 2.7.3; however, when I use python 3.2.3, I get an error stating `'dict_values' object does not support indexing`.  How can I modify the code to make it compatible for 3.2.3?

Comment: `values` now returns a view object http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects

Comment: Why are you relying on the order of the `values` returned from a dictionary anyway?

Comment: Yeah, this code is unreliable unless d is an `OrderedDict` - and even if it is is seems like there must be a better way.

Comment: A case I use it in is when I know there is only one key value in the dict from say a database row retrieval for one column only in dict format per row.  I think it is extremely poor that values() cannot auto_convert when indexed.

Answer (score 245, accepted):

In Python 3, `dict.values()` (along with `dict.keys()` and `dict.items()`) returns a `view`, rather than a list. See the documentation [here](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects). You therefore need to wrap your call to `dict.values()` in a call to `list` like so:

```
v = list(d.values())
{names[i]:v[i] for i in range(len(names))}
```

Comment: The OP's code is unpythonic for everyone looking at this - in Python we avoid indexes (slower, uglier). The correct way is as per @DavidRobinson's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17431678/281545): `dict(zip(names, d.values()))`. Of course this code also relies on values being sorted as names which is by no means guaranteed.

Comment: If you can, would you care to explain python's rationale behind this decision? From a naive perspective I don't see any reason why the view should not allow indexing in this particular case. I assume there is a grander scheme behind the view concept that does not play with indexing, but some clarity would be appreciated.

Comment: For those reading these comments, @Mr_and_Mrs_D's version of this implementation is UNSAFE. You should not rely on dictionary order. For example doing `d=dict(**d)` may change the iteration order of keys.

Comment: @xaviersjs no it may not in python 3.7+ - it is a guarantee of the language. But this has nothing to do with my comment - iterating over the dict is equivalent as iterating over the `keys()` which in turn _is_ guaranteed to have the same order as iterating over the `values()` - aka `list(d.values()) == list(d[k] for k in d.keys()) == list(d[k] for k in d)`

Answer (score 20):

A simpler version of your code would be:

```
dict(zip(names, d.values()))
```

If you want to keep the same structure, you can change it to:

```
vlst = list(d.values())
{names[i]: vlst[i] for i in range(len(names))}
```

(You can just as easily put `list(d.values())` inside the comprehension instead of `vlst`; it's just wasteful to do so since it would be re-generating the list every time).

Comment: Unfortuately, when I use the vlst example, I get an error "'dict' object has no attribute 'values'

Comment: @JessePet: I don't see how that's possible, especially since in your own code `d.values()` did work without an error (until you tried to index it). Is it possible you misspelled `values` or some simliar error?

Comment: I did not misspell values, it's astounding me to say the least

Comment: @JessePet: What happens if you open a new Python3 terminal and do `{1: 2}.values()`? Or `d = {1: 2}; print d.values()`?

Comment: I get dict(values[2]) as an output.  My issue is that the comprehension will not let me iterate through the values (i in this case) of the dictionary d

Comment: Can you paste the precise code you are using and the error you are getting?

Answer (score 12):

In Python 3 the `dict.values()` method returns a [dictionary view object](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects), *not* a list like it does in Python 2. Dictionary views have a length, can be iterated, and support membership testing, but don't support indexing.

To make your code work in both versions, you could use either of these:

```
{names[i]:value for i,value in enumerate(d.values())}
```

***or***

```
values = list(d.values())
{name:values[i] for i,name in enumerate(names)}
```

By far the simplest, fastest way to do the same thing in either version would be:

```
dict(zip(names, d.values()))
```

since `zip()` doesn't care one way or the other.

Note however, that all of these methods will give you results that will vary depending on the actual contents of `d`. To overcome that, you may be able use an [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)<sup>**✶**</sup> instead, which remembers the order that keys were first inserted into it, so you can count on the order of what is returned by the `values()` method.

**<sup>✶</sup> Update**  in Python 3.7+ regular dictionaries maintain insertion order, so using an `OrderedDict` would no longer be necessary. (Actually they were also that way in CPython 3.6, but it wasn't official yet — i.e. in the sense that it was merely an *implementation detail*, not part of the *language specification*).