# Django Aggregation: Sum return value only?

Tags: python, django, sum, aggregation

I have a list of values paid and want to display the total paid. I have used aggregation and `Sum` to calculate the values together. The problem is,I just want the total value printed out, but aggregation prints out: `{'amount__sum': 480.0}` (480.0 being the total value added.

In my View, I have:

```
    from django.db.models import Sum

    total_paid = Payment.objects.all.aggregate(Sum('amount'))
```

And to show the value on the page, I have a mako template with the following:

```
    <p><strong>Total Paid:</strong> ${total_paid}</p>
```

How would I get it to show `480.0` instead of `{'amount__sum': 480.0}`?

Comment: How about `aggregate(sum = Sum('amount'))` and in the template `${total_paid.sum}`

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I don't believe there is a way to get only the value.

You could just do `${{ total_paid.amount__sum }}` in your template. Or do `total_paid = Payment.objects.all().aggregate(Sum('amount')).get('amount__sum', 0.00)` in your view.

**EDIT**

As others have pointed out, `.aggregate()` will always return a dictionary with all of the keys from the aggregates present, so doing `.get()` on the result is not necessary. However, if the queryset is empty, each aggregate value would be `None`. So depending on your code, if you are expecting a float, you could do:

`total_paid = Payment.objects.all().aggregate(Sum('amount'))['amount__sum'] or 0.00`

Comment: Thank you for this. I had already tried ${{ total_paid.amount__sum }} but it didnt work. But calling it in the View worked nicely!

Comment: @jproffitt, could you give me an example when you will not have a dictionary with the key `'amount__sum'` if the aggregation executes successfully?

Comment: @lmiguelvargasf You are correct. There is no need to do `.get`. I have made an edit to my answer.

Answer (score 34):

Give it a name and then ask for it:

```
total_paid = Payment.objects.all.aggregate(sum=Sum('amount'))['sum']
```

Should be little more readable, and there is no need for conversion.

Comment: it's the shortest and consicest answer

Comment: Just as a note, try not using names of builtin functions such as [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum)

Answer (score 25):

The `aggregate()` method returns a dictionary. If you know you're only returning a single-entry dictionary you could use `.values()[0]`.

In **Python 2**:

```
total_paid = Payment.objects.aggregate(Sum('amount')).values()[0]
```

In **Python 3**, (thanks @lmiguelvargasf) this will need to be:

```
total_paid = list(Payment.objects.aggregate(Sum('amount')).values())[0]
```

The end result is the same as @jproffitt's answer, but it avoids repeating the `amount__sum` part, so it's a little more generic.

Comment: This is my preferred solution too.  `values()` has [changed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17431638/get-typeerror-dict-values-object-does-not-support-indexing-when-using-python) in Python 3 to return a view rather than a list.  Passing the return of `values()` through `list()` makes this solution work then.

Comment: I agree with @TaylorEdmiston, this code is not working on Python 3. I have added an answer that solves it.

Comment: Thank you @lmiguelvargasf.  To help others in the future, I have also just submitted a community edit to this answer adding the line for python 3.  I believe it will be visible to others after it's peer approved.

Answer (score 3):

**In Python 3**:

You can solve it by converting the `dict_values` to a `list`:

```
total_paid = list(Payment.objects.aggregate(Sum('amount')).values())[0] or 0 # the or 0 is required in case the query is an empty query set.
```

The previous code avoids using `'column_name__sum'` as key, but in case you prefer the dictionary way:

```
total_paid = Payment.objects.aggregate(Sum('amount'))['amount__sum'] or 0
```

In terms of efficiency, I made a test with some data I have, and it seems that using the dictionary key is faster:

```
In [9]: %timeit total = Pledge.objects.filter(user=user, group__isnull=True).aggregate(Sum('amount'))['amount__sum'] or 0
3.13 ms ± 25.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

In [10]: %timeit total = list(Pledge.objects.filter(user=user, group__isnull=True).aggregate(Sum('amount')).values())[0] or 0
3.22 ms ± 61.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

In terms of readability, I think that @mehmet's solution is the best one, and I have also test its efficiency:

```
In [18]: %timeit Pledge.objects.filter(user=user, group__isnull=True).aggregate(sum=Sum('amount'))['sum'] or 0
3.22 ms ± 124 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Answer (score 0):

(It's only useful if you used decimal field)
Store a key value in a new variable and convert it to the float if you're using a decimal. I think it's the easiest way

```
total_paid = Payment.objects.all.aggregate(Sum('amount'))
# output: {'amount__sum':Decimal('0000.000000')
tp=total_paid['amount__sum']
new_total_paid=float(tp)
```

Answer (score 0):

100% you can solve your demand by this technique

```py
from django.db.models import Sum

sum_count = Payment.objects.aggregate(Sum('amount'))
totalAmonut = sum_count['Qty__sum']
```