# Python looping thru dictionary to access item by index

Tags: python, for-loop

I was having some problem when trying to sort for dates to be grouped by month in Python. Here is my code:

```
data_dict =  dict()
for yhat in forecast:
    inverted = inverse_difference(history, yhat, days_in_year)
    #print('Day %d: %f' % (day, inverted))
    data_dict[day] = inverted
    day += 1

# group all the forecasted data by month
default_month = (lambda: data_dict)
month_groups = defaultdict(default_month)
year = 2017
for day, value in data_dict.items():
    month = datetime.strptime('{:0>3}-{}'.format(day, year), '%j-%Y').month
    month_groups[month] = month_groups.values()[month] + value

for key, value in month_groups.items():
    print(key)
    print(value)
```

Some sample inputs:

```
Day 1: -109.743833
Day 2: -59.743030
Day 3: -149.539798
Day 4: -134.004097
Day 5: -101.911757
Day 6: -64.655886
Day 7: 38.683420
Day 8: 14.493554
Day 9: -52.823889
Day 10: -16.754896
Day 11: 27.648000
Day 12: -8.978296
Day 13: 3.077756
Day 14: 8.925626
Day 15: -13.099969
Day 16: 36.508620
Day 17: -20.888302
Day 18: 2.014708
Day 19: 52.070549
Day 20: 14.389047
Day 21: 46.281278
Day 22: 6.589799
Day 23: 14.849905
Day 24: 21.924614
Day 25: -19.006338
Day 26: -16.249006
Day 27: 41.147836
Day 28: 25.397426
Day 29: 45.358489
Day 30: 129.366465
Day 31: 129.377892
Day 32: -16.628081
Day 33: 56.484472
Day 34: 73.509385
Day 35: 119.484387
Day 36: -21.506795
Day 37: -16.499800
Day 38: -17.491308
Day 39: 140.532548
Day 40: -8.470736
Day 41: 203.523499
```

I wanted to group day 1 to 31 and sum up their total to print out in the last for loop. However, I am getting this error message:

```
TypeError: 'dict_values' object does not support indexing
```

at line `month_groups[month] = month_groups.values()[month] + value`

Any ideas how to fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the following change,

```
month_groups = defaultdict(int)
```

Then you can just do

```
month_groups[month] += value
```

Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17431638/get-typeerror-dict-values-object-does-not-support-indexing-when-using-python) regarding your error

Comment: Nope it does not work. I am getting this error message TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'dict' and 'float'

Comment: your month_groups dict contains total value for each month right? I assumed you have properly initialized month_groups dictionary for each month (that is 0) in defaultdict

Comment: Yes. I only initialized it like this: month_groups = defaultdict(default_month)

Comment: Hmm it is just an import like this: from collections import defaultdict

Comment: Use  `month_groups = defaultdict(int)`

Comment: I see I see. Thanks so much!!