# Which of these two functions is most optimal based on Big O notation

Tags: python-3.x, optimization

I was curious between these two functions, which is most optimal and what Big O notation category would you assign to each and why?

## Function 1

```
def __getitem__(self, search_key):
    for key, value in self.items():
        if key == search_key:
            return value
    raise KeyError('key {} not found'.format(search_key))
```

## Function 2

```
def __getitem__(self, key):
    if key in self.keys():
        return self.values()[self.keys().index(key)]
    else:
        raise KeyError('key {} not found'.format(key))
```

Comment: Function 1 is much more efficient because of your `index` call in function 2 (which to be honest I didn't think `index` works on dictionary keys). Function 1 also will short circuit.

Comment: would you classify function 1 as O(N) and function 2 as O(N2) ?

Comment: Both are `O(N)`. The second one has a worst case of `O(3N)` which is still `O(N)`. The first one has worst case `O(N)`..

Comment: wouldn't **if key in self.keys():** be O(N) and then the **return self.values()[self.keys().index(key)]** be O(N) as well (from the index call), leading to O(N2) overall ?

Comment: You dont do `return self.values()[self.keys().index(key)]` every loop. You only do it once. Also that line is `O(2N)` (still `O(N)` technically) because you use both `keys()` and `values()`.

Comment: how would you say function 2 has worst case O(3N) ?

Comment: `if key in self.keys()` iterates over the keys once, `self.keys().index(key)` iterates over the keys again (because you did the `index` call), and finally `self.values()` iterates over the `dict` a third time.

Comment: thank you so much your explanation is excellent.  One last question, why is O(3N) still O(N) ?

Comment: Big O notation normally ignore minor multiplications. 8N is the same as N.  8N^2 is the same as N^2.  Its just how that notation works.

Comment: is O(2^N) the same as the O(2N) you  refer to?

Comment: No. When I say O(2N) I mean O(2*N).  O(2^N) is completely different (and the most inefficient version of big O notation. [Read up on big O](https://www.interviewcake.com/article/java/big-o-notation-time-and-space-complexity)

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse another quick comment (thanks for everything), I understand **if key in self.keys()** iterates over the dict, and that **self.keys().index(key)** also iterates over the dict BUT does simply calling **self.values()** really cause iteration over the dict?

Comment: To be clear the `keys` of a `dict` is a `set` which is `O(1)` look up time but because you iterate with the `keys` it becomes `O(n)`.  The only way to get a value out of a `dict` is to use the `key`.  Thus by calling `.values()` the `dict` is using each `key` to get each `value`.

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse so would Function2 be more accurately O(2N) ?

Comment: O(3N) because you use .index on the keys and you call .values, plus you iterate with the for loop. So you do three iterations.

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse OK!  so **.values()** is O(N).  Is that because .values() causes iteration ?  Thanks for all your insight.

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse cant find any resources to show that .values() is O(N) :/

Comment: Thats a implementation detail of dictionaries. You would have to look up the source code and it would be specific to your type of python. pypy, cpython, jpython, etc.  Look up how hash tables work and you should see why it is O(n).

Comment: unless im missing something, according to this https://www.ics.uci.edu/~pattis/ICS-33/lectures/complexitypython.txt .values() is actually considered O(1)   !  @Error-SyntacticalRemorse

Comment: As I said initially, your code [isn't valid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17431638/get-typeerror-dict-values-object-does-not-support-indexing-when-using-python). The values call is technically O(1) but you index it which means you need to turn it into a list.  If you want to test it then write some code with varying size dictionary and print the values. If it was O(1) then the time required to get the values should be constant.