# How to access elements in a dict_values?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, python-collections

I have a dict :

```
{49: {'created_at': '2018-11-07T13:25:12.000Z', 'url': 'https://www.test.com'}}
```

I would like to get 'created_at'.

I've attempt through different methods but without a success... I thought this approach would works:

`result = di.values()[0]` but I get a `TypeError: 'dict_values' object does not support indexing`

But it doesn't.

Comment: `result = di['49']['created_at']`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get: TypeError: 'dict\_values' object does not support indexing when using python 3.2.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17431638/get-typeerror-dict-values-object-does-not-support-indexing-when-using-python)

Comment: @Gregoire check Josh's post, you need to cast the d1.values() to a list before accessing element 0

Comment: Why the downvote? I have this question too. It's relevantly worded such that it brought me here. I wanted to now how to access these `dict_values/dict_keys` w/o having constantly cast to a list; how to use these objs natively? It's not discussed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use: `di[49]['created_at']`

or:

`list(di.values())[0]['created_at']`

Comment: Thanks @Gabip . The first solution doesn't work (KeyError: '49'). But the second does the job perfectly

Answer (score 1):

You may use dict items for it.

```
dic = {49: {'created_at': '2018-11-07T13:25:12.000Z', 'url': 'https://www.test.com'}}
for j,k in dic.items():
     print(k['created_at'])
```