# How can I use gkeepapi to retrieve and print out the labels associated with my Google Keep notes?

Tags: python, google-keep-api

## Background

I am using `gkeepapi` to get the labels of my Google Keep notes:

```py
import gkeepapi
keep = gkeepapi.Keep()
keep.login('user@gmail.com', 'password')
labels = keep.labels()
```

I want to read the data from `labels`. I expect it should be as easy as `console.log(labels)` in JavaScript.

## Problem

To read the `labels` code, I try various suggestions from [How do I look inside a Python object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1006169/3416774):

```py
print("\nlabels:\n", labels)
print("\ntype(labels):\n", type(labels))
print("\nlist(labels):\n", list(labels))
print("\nlabels.__dir__:\n", labels.__dir__)
print("\ndir(labels):\n", dir(labels))
print("\nlist(labels.values())\n:", list(labels.values()))
print("\nlabels.__dict__:\n", labels.__dict__)
```

The result:

```py
labels:
 dict_values([<gkeepapi.node.Label object at 0x0000023C546C40D0>, <gkeepapi.node.Label object at 0x0000023C54BB5750>, <gkeepapi.node.Label object at 0x0000023C54BB7E90>, <gkeepapi.node.Label object at 0x0000023C54BC4310>])

type(labels):
 <class 'dict_values'>

list(labels):
 [<gkeepapi.node.Label object at 0x0000023C546C40D0>, <gkeepapi.node.Label object at 0x0000023C54BB5750>, <gkeepapi.node.Label object at 0x0000023C54BB7E90>, <gkeepapi.node.Label object at 0x0000023C54BC4310>]

labels.__dir__:
 <built-in method __dir__ of dict_values object at 0x0000023C54F057E0>

dir(labels):
 ['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getstate__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__init_subclass__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__reversed__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'mapping']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\QC supplements\Code\Apps\Trấn Kỳ\test.py", line 24, in <module>
    print("\nlist(labels.values())\n:", list(labels.values()))
                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^  
AttributeError: 'dict_values' object has no attribute 'values'
```

None of them actually show me the data. What should I do?

Comment: `labels` already denotes the dict values

Comment: Can you include the code where you define labels? This code is not sufficient to explain where you've gone wrong, but it would appear that `labels` has been assigned to a `dict.values()` call. You should simply call `print(labels)` to read the data

Comment: @bc1155 I update the question. Can you take a look?

Comment: So `labels` doesn't have a `__dict__` attribute; but you don't need it either. So you can ignore using a `__dict__` attribute for it, easy.

Comment: @9769953 I've added back the `list(labels.values())` line. It's just another attempt to read the data. If I don't use the `__dict__` attribute, what should I do then?

Comment: You can iterate over  the `labels` using `for obj in labels` and print the `dir(obj)` to see what all properties available to `gkeepapi.node.Label`object

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM thanks. That works. So contradict to what `type(labels)` says (`<class 'dict_values'>`), `labels` is a list, not an object?

Comment: Why do you need the `__dict__` attribute?

Comment: You can look at the reference manual [here](https://gkeepapi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gkeepapi.html#gkeepapi.Keep.labels). It looks like you can do `[label.name for label in labels]` to get a list of label names.

Comment: `list(labels)` shows you the data. If you don't like the `<gkeepapi.node.Label object at 0x0000023C546C40D0>` represenation (because you're looking at the `repr` form of those objects), you can try `print([str(label) for label in labels])`.

Comment: @9769953 I don't know what it does either. I thought that it would help me inspect the object so I try

Comment: It can help, but generally only minimally. If it's not there, just ignore it and don't use it; it's not required.

Comment: @Ooker `labels` here is not a list. `labels` a view of the dictionary’s values. For example create a dummy dictionary `foo = {1: 2}` and print `type(foo.values())`

Comment: @AbdulNiyasPM when it says `<class 'dict_values'>`, does that mean it's an object belongs to class `dict_values`? Is a view a kind of object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you pointed out in the comments, the `dict_values` you are seeing is a [dictionary view object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects), as also mentioned similarly from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17431716/13642249). If you want to just print out the names of the labels, you can iterate and print through them. Converting them to a list can also be useful for other desires as well.

The example below will iterate through and call that object's `name` method `gkeepapi.node.Label` objects (see [here](https://gkeepapi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gkeepapi.html#gkeepapi.node.Label) for reference). You can save the labels in a list as well for other uses.

```
import gkeepapi

keep = gkeepapi.Keep()
keep.login('user@gmail.com', 'password')

labels = keep.labels()

for label in labels:
    label_text = label.name
    print(label_text)

list_of_labels = list(labels) #option for other post use
```