# Iterating over Dictionary Items in Python to perform sets of calculations

Tags: python, dictionary, iteration, computation

I have a dictionary `dict` which has two values per key, like so:

```
dict = {}
dict[name] = x1, x2
```

Let's say that this dictionary has 10 items in it. I would like to iterate over the keys of the dictionary such that I'm performing a calculation for each key-values set with respect to the other key-values sets in the dictionary. For instance, I would like to start at the first key and calculate something like x1_0 + x2_0 - x1_1 + x2_1, where "_0" denotes the first key's values and "_1" denotes the values associated with any other key's values. This calculation would be performed nine times with respect to all other nine keys. Then I would move to the second key-values set and perform the calculations with respect to the nine remaining keys, and so on.

I have tried doing this with two dictionaries containing the same data, but have been unsuccessful. Note that I've already done a float conversion for the values, so that is not the problem. Here is what I've tried:

```
for (name_0, (x1_0, x2_0)), (name_1, (x1_1, x2_1)) in zip(dict.iteritems(), dict2.iteritems()):
    if name_0 != name_1:
        d = x1_0 + x2_0 - x1_1 + x2_1
    print d
```

Comment: There is no *first key*, dicts are unordered

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326658/python-index-a-dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using indexing when initializing the for loop and this has worked very well:

```
for (dict.keys()[i], dict.values()[i]), (dict2.keys()[j], dict2.values()[j]) in zip(dict.iteritems(), dict2.iteritems()):
```

Answer (score 1):

If my understanding is correct, you intend to perform a permutation of each of the couplet. With the resultant couplet pair, you would intend to perform some ad-hoc calculation

Let  one of the Pair P<sub>i</sub> be (X<sub>i</sub>, X<sub>j</sub>) where X<sub>i</sub> is a couplet (X<sub>i0</sub>, X<sub>i1</sub>) then the formulation could be expressed as

```
def calc(x):
    return x[0][0] + x[0][1] - x[1][0] + x[1][1]
```

To create a pairwise permutation, you can use [itertools.permutation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations) as follows

```
permutations(_dict.values(), 2)
```

Now you just need to map the couplet pair with your formulated function

```
map(calc, permutations(d.values(), 2))
```