# Pulling a value from a dictionary in Python by index?

Tags: python

```
def max_n_min(dic):
dic_list = dic.items()[0]
max = min = dic_list
for value in dic.values():
    if value > max:
        max = value
    if value < min:
        min = value
return(max, min) 

 <ipython-input-16-5837f0a5d1aa> in max_n_min(dic)
  1 #Sums births for a requested periods
  2 def max_n_min(dic):    
----> 3     dic_list = dic.values()[0]
  4     max = min = dic_list
  5     for value in dic.values()    
TypeError: 'dict_values' object does not support indexing
```

I'm making a function that takes the values of the keys in a dictionary as input, and outputs the max and min of those values. All values and keys are integers. I want to set the default max and min as the value of the first key, but for some reason it's giving me the above TypeError. This is strange to me because in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326658/python-index-a-dictionary#) thread, it seems to be the recommended solution.

Comment: can you show the `dic` contents?

Comment: Your usage of the word **values** is confusing.

Comment: Dictionaries are unorderd, so you have no guarantee that the "first" value will be the same.

Comment: The comment you reference uses a [collections.OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict)

Answer (score 1):

Because `dict.values()` returns a object of `dict_values` type. In order to make this work, you have to type-cast it to list (or tuple) as:

```
list(dic.values())[0]
```

Sample run:

```
>>> my_dict = {1: 2, 3: 4}

# Your syntax; raising error
>>> my_dict.values()[1]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'dict_values' object does not support indexing

# type-casted to list; works fine
>>> list(my_dict.values())[1]
4
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt response. As this is my first post, i feel very enthusiastic about continuing to use stack overflow as a reference.

Comment: This is **dangerous**: `dct.values()` is inherently **unordered**. Each time you call it you can get a different order.

Comment: That's true. I just helped you finding the issue you faced. In case you want to maintain the order, you definitely should not be using `dict.values()` of normal `dict`. However, you may prevent yourself from it via using `collections.OrderedDict` whose `dict.values()` returns the ordered response

Comment: For the purposes of this program I actually prefer unordered to ordered.

Comment: Dicts are no longer unordered in later pythons.  Also, `tuple()` will use less memory if the dict is sizable.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the same shorter using internals:

```py
def max_n_min(dic):
    return (max(dic.values()), min(dic.values()))
```