# How to get nested dictionary from JSON in Python

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I would like to take some JSON, convert it into a dictionary and then change some of the values in that dictionary.

I've tried a few things as shown below but I can't get it to work as intended.

My JSON is as follows:

```
{
   "9":[
      {
         "09_000":{
            "name":"Wyatt Feldt",
            "1":"R",
            "2":"L",
            "w":1,
            "h_t":1
         }
      },
      {
         "09_001":{
            "name":"Clayton Friend",
            "1":"R",
            "2":"R",
            "w":0,
            "h_t":0
         }
      }
   ],
   "10":[
      {
         "09_000":{
            "name":"Wyatt Feldt",
            "1":"R",
            "2":"L",
            "w":1,
            "h_t":1
         }
      },
      {
         "09_001":{
            "name":"Clayton Friend",
            "1":"R",
            "2":"R",
            "w":0,
            "h_t":0
         }
      }
   ],
   "11":[
      {
         "09_000":{
            "name":"Wyatt Feldt",
            "1":"R",
            "2":"L",
            "w":1,
            "h_t":1
         }
      },
      {
         "09_001":{
            "name":"Clayton Friend",
            "1":"R",
            "2":"R",
            "w":0,
            "h_t":0
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

And then in Python I have written `print(my_data["9"][0])` which returns {'09_000': {'name': 'Wyatt Feldt', '1': 'R', '2': 'L', 'w': 1, 'h_t': 1}}.

However, I just want it to return {'name': 'Wyatt Feldt', '1': 'R', '2': 'L', 'w': 1, 'h_t': 1} because I don't just want to print it, I want to set some of the values e.g. the name. And I know I can do that by doing `my_data["9"][0]["09_000"]` but I don't want to use that ID in order to get it (only the outer group, the index and then the key e.g. "name"). Since I'm already returning {'09_000': {'name': 'Wyatt Feldt', '1': 'R', '2': 'L', 'w': 1, 'h_t': 1}} I'm sure there must be a way to just get the nested part ({'name': 'Wyatt Feldt', '1': 'R', '2': 'L', 'w': 1, 'h_t': 1}) so I can change the values.

EDIT: I think it's a different issue. My `my_data` variable is already in dictionary format, and this is a special case of indexing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting JSON String to Dictionary Not List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19483351/converting-json-string-to-dictionary-not-list)

Comment: @Primusa No I don't think so.

Comment: There's two parts to this question. The first part of the question is how to convert a json string to a dict. The second part is how to index a dictionary: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326658/how-to-index-into-a-dictionary

Comment: @Primusa I edited to clarify that I have already achieved the first part. And the second part is different to the one you have linked.

Comment: To get a specific value from a dictionary you generally have to index it. If there's just one value you can do something like `val = list(dict.values())[0]`

Comment: `print(list(my_data["9"][0].values())[0])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if you know there's only one key-value pair in the inner dictionary and you just want its value, you can enumerate the values and then access the first one, like so:

```py
wyatt = list(my_data["9"][0].values())[0] # {'name': 'Wyatt Feldt', ... }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have your JSON text in a string, say its name is `my_json`, then you can use Python's `json.loads` to convert it to a dictionary.

```
import json
register = json.loads(my_json)
```

In side your dictionary, you have keys "9", "10", "11".  For each of those, you have a list of two items you can iterate through.  And each of the items in the list is a dictionary of one key.  You could just iterate through these last keys without knowing what they are:

```
for k in register:
    for block in register[k]:
        for block_key in block:
            print(block[block_key])
```

The output I get from this is:

```
{u'1': u'R', u'h_t': 1, u'2': u'L', u'name': u'Wyatt Feldt', u'w': 1}
{u'1': u'R', u'h_t': 0, u'2': u'R', u'name': u'Clayton Friend', u'w': 0}
{u'1': u'R', u'h_t': 1, u'2': u'L', u'name': u'Wyatt Feldt', u'w': 1}
{u'1': u'R', u'h_t': 0, u'2': u'R', u'name': u'Clayton Friend', u'w': 0}
{u'1': u'R', u'h_t': 1, u'2': u'L', u'name': u'Wyatt Feldt', u'w': 1}
{u'1': u'R', u'h_t': 0, u'2': u'R', u'name': u'Clayton Friend', u'w': 0}
```

If you know that your lists are always going to contain items of one key, then another way to do it is use `block.keys()` to generate the list of dictionary keys, then take the first (and only) item in the list:

```
for k in register:
    for block in register[k]:
        print(block[block.keys()[0]])
```

In any case, you can replace the `print` statement I've used with some command to change whatever you need.  Though to make it easier to get to the right location, try using the index numbers of the list:

```
for k in register:
    for i in range(len(register[k])):
        for key in register[k][i]:
            original_name = register[k][i][key][u'name']
            if original_name == u'Wyatt Feldt':
                register[k][i][key][u'name'] = 'Wyatt Erp'
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Primusa for the comment.

I have done `print(list(my_data["9"][0].values())[0])` and it works as intended.

Comment: @davedwards It says I can't answer my own question for 2 days.

Comment: @davedwards Someone else commented the same thing after me anyway, so I just accepted that one.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access that particular element, then you can do something like the following:

```
n_entry = 0
entry_key_name = f'09_{n_entry:03}'  # If using >= python 3.6
# entry_key_name = '09_{:03}'.format(n_entry)  # If using < python 3.6
print(register["9"][n_entry][entry_key_name])
```

Result:

```
{'name': 'Wyatt Feldt', '1': 'R', '2': 'L', 'w': 1, 'h_t': 1}
```