# How to compare index values of list in default dict in python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a default dict `d` in python which contains two list in it as below:

```
{
    'data1': [0.8409093126477928, 0.9609093126477928, 0.642217399079215, 0.577003839123445, 0.7024399719949195, 1.0739533732043967], 
    'data2':  [0.9662666242560285, 0.9235637581239243, 0.8947656867577896, 0.9266919525550584, 1.0220039913024457]
}
```

In future there can be many list in in default dict like `data1`, `data2`, `data3`, `data4` etc. I need to compare the index values of default dict with each other. So for above default dict I need to check weather `data1[0]->0.8409093126477928` is smaller than `data2[0]->0.9662666242560285` or not and same goes for other index, and store the result of wining list index in separate list like below:

```
result = ['data1', 'data2', 'data1', 'data1', 'data1']
```

If length of any list is greater than other list, we simply need to check if the last index value is smaller than 1 or not. Like `data1[5]` cannot be compared with `data2[5]` because there is no value of `data2[5]` thus we will simply check if `data1[5]` is less than 1 or not. If its less than 1 then we will consider it and add it to `result` otherwise ignore it and will not save it in `result`.

To resolve this I thought, of extracting the list from default dict to separate list and then using a for loop to compare index values, but when I did `print(d[0])` to print the `0th` index list, it printed out `[]`. Why is it printing null. How can I compare the index values as above. Please help. Thanks

Comment: This may help with your problem: [How to index into a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326658/how-to-index-into-a-dictionary)

Comment: I could use a bit of clarification on what to do when there are lists longer than others. Do we do the "less than 1" thing only if there's a single list left, or if any list is missing? If the latter, which one of the remaining lists do we take?

Comment: What happens when they're equal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**: as suggested by @ggorlen replaced the custom iterator with zip_longest

I would do it using custom_iterator like this,

- zip longest yeild one item from each array in each iteration. for shorter array it will return 1 when iteration goes past its length
- The list comprehension loop through the iterator and get 1st index of min item `item.index(min(item))` then get the key corresponding to the min value `keys[item.index(min(item))]`
- if selected list is shorter than current iterator index it either skips or give "NA" value

```py
from itertools import zip_longest

keys = list(d.keys())
lengths = list(map(len,d.values()))

result = [keys[item.index(min(item))] 
          for i, item in enumerate(zip_longest(*d.values(), fillvalue=1))
          if lengths[item.index(min(item))]>i]

result
```

if you want to give default key instead of skip-ing when minimum value found is not less than one

```py
result = [keys[item.index(min(item))] if lengths[item.index(min(item))]>i else "NA"
          for i, item in enumerate(zip_longest(*d.values(), fillvalue=1))]
```

Comment: Thankyou. Can you explain this logic please.?

Comment: I'm getting different results running this on the example in my post: `['quux', 'foo', 'baz', 'foo', 'bar', 'foo', 'baz']`. Not sure how that last `"foo"` gets in there. I think using `col.append(arr[i] if i< len(arr) else 1)` for padding breaks the logic because the default placeholder value of 1 can inadvertently be interpreted as a minimum value and generate false positives, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: @DevKhadka I am getting the correct results `['data1', 'data2', 'data1', 'data1', 'data1', 'data2']` but not sure why its appending `data2` as last item in `result`. Also I am still trying to understand this logic, can you explain where exactly you are appending the `data1` or `data2` in result list please.?

Comment: @SAndrew can you comment on the correctness of my response? I'm pretty curious if my example matches what you're asking for. If so, it should work for you.

Comment: The iterator is giving default value 1 for shorter list, so when iterator goes past the shorter list and other list have value greater than 1 it will choose key of 1st list

Comment: I don't think using 1 as a default is going to work. It should be something like `None` so you can identify the difference between a placeholder and an actual list with a 1 in it.

Comment: ya, you have a point, I am using 1 because @SAndrew want to take values less than one. I will work if other list have value less than one but if not then it will return key of 1st shorter list. I think we can return some value indicating "NA" in that case

Comment: Yeah, but all of that is essentially re-writing `zip_longest`, right?

Comment: ya @ggorlen is right, I have modified answer using zip_longest

Answer (score 1):

We can use [`zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest) from itertools and a variety of loops to achieve the result:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

result = []
pairs = [[[z, y] for z in x] for y, x in data.items()]

for x in zip_longest(*pairs):
    x = [y for y in x if y]

    if len(x) > 1:
        result.append(min(x, key=lambda x: x[0])[1])
    elif x[0][0] < 1:
        result.append(x[0][1])

print(result) # => ['data1', 'data2', 'data1', 'data1', 'data1']
```

First we create pairs of every item in each dict value and its key. This makes it easier to get result keys later. We `zip_longest` and iterate over the lists, filtering out `None`s. If we have more than one element to compare, we take the min and append it to the result, else we check the lone element and keep it if its value is less than 1.

A more verifiable example is

```
data = {
    'foo':  [1, 0, 1, 0], 
    'bar':  [1, 1, 1, 1, 0],
    'baz':  [1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
    'quux': [0],
}
```

which produces

```
['quux', 'foo', 'baz', 'foo', 'bar', 'baz']
```

Element-wise, `"quux"` wins round 0, `"foo"` wins round 1, `"baz"` 2, `"foo"` round 3 thanks to key order (tied with `"baz"`), `"bar"` for round 4. For round 5, `"baz"` is the last one standing but isn't below 1, so nothing is taken. For round 6, `"baz"` is still the last one standing but since 0 < 1, it's taken.

Answer (score 1):

```
d = {
    'd0': [0.1, 1.1, 0.3],
    'd1': [0.4, 0.5, 1.4, 0.3, 1.6],
    'd2': [],
}

import itertools
import collections

# sort by length of lists, shortest first and longest last
d = sorted(d.items(), key=lambda k:len(k[1]))

# loop through all combinations possible
for (key1, list1), (key2, list2) in itertools.combinations(d, 2):
    result = []
    for v1, v2 in itertools.zip_longest(list1, list2): # shorter list is padded with None
        # no need to check if v2 is None because of sorting
        if v1 is None:
            result.append(key2 if v2 < 1 else None)
        else:
            result.append(key1 if v1 < v2 else key2)

    # DO stuff with result, keys, list, etc...
    print(f'{key1} vs {key2} = {result}')
```

Output

```
d2 vs d0 = ['d0', None, 'd0']
d2 vs d1 = ['d1', 'd1', None, 'd1', None]
d0 vs d1 = ['d0', 'd1', 'd0', 'd1', None]
```

---

I sorted them based on the list lengths. This ensures that `list1` will always be shorter or of the same length as `list2`.

For different lengths, the remaining indices will be a mixture of `None` and `key2`.

However, when the elements are equal, `key2` is added to the result. This might not be the desired behavior.