# performing an operation on the list of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary

I would like to add an extra key called `"centroid"` to this `loc1` and `loc2` dictionary by using some custom centroid calculation function.  `location_list` is the list of dictionaries `loc1` and `loc2`

```
location_list = [loc1,loc2]

loc1 = {
"x_cor" : 10,
"y_cor" : 20}

loc2 = {
"x_cor" : 10,
"y_cor" : 25}
```

I would like to get the centroid of these two locations and add an extra key "centroid" to both loc1 and loc2.

The function for calculating centroid is as follows:

```
 def get_centroid(self, locations: list):
        
        x, y = [p[0] for p in locations], [p[1] for p in locations]
        centroid = [round(sum(x) / len(locations), 2), round(sum(y) / len(locations), 2)]
        return centroid
```

Expected output:

```
loc1 = {
    "x_cor" : 10,
    "y_cor" : 20,
"centroid": (6.667 , 15)}
    
    loc2 = {
    "x_cor" : 10,
    "y_cor" : 25,
"centroid": (6.667 , 15)}
```

Is there a way I can use this function to add an extra key "centroid" to these dictionaries?

Comment: Is it compulsory to use that function? It looks incorrect

Comment: @Sujay Not compulsory but I would like to get the centroid as the key.

Comment: What is the current output of your code?

Comment: first call the function then update the individual dictionaries with result or use for loop if you have more than two dicts

Answer (score 0):

```py
 def get_centroid(self, locations: list):
        
        x, y = [p[0] for p in locations], [p[1] for p in locations]
        centroid = [round(sum(x) / len(locations), 2), round(sum(y) / len(locations), 2)]
        for location in locations:
            location['centroid'] = centroid
        return centroid
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `get_centroid` function does not work. You can't access dictionary items using index as dictionaries are unordered, [Index into dictionary.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326658/how-to-index-into-a-dictionary)

This means you'll have to replace `p[0]` for `p['x_cor']` and `p[1]` for `p['y_cor']`.

I don't think you need `self` as an argument in `get_centroid`. `self` isn't used in the function code and they are used in classes mostly.

To add the centroid to `loc1` and `loc2` you can use a for loop.

```
for loc in locations:
        loc['centroid'] = centroid
    return locations
```

Combine this into your `get_centroid` function to get this:

```
def get_centroid(locations: list):
    x, y = [p['x_cor'] for p in locations], [p['y_cor'] for p in locations]
    centroid = [round(sum(x) / len(locations), 2), round(sum(y) / len(locations), 2)]
    for loc in locations:
        loc['centroid'] = centroid
    return locations
```

Using your supplied x and y co-ordinate values and the centroid equation, I wasn't able to achieve your expected output. The output I achieved for the centroid was (10.0, 22.5).

**Whole code**

```
def get_centroid(locations: list):
    x, y = [p['x_cor'] for p in locations], [p['y_cor'] for p in locations]
    centroid = [round(sum(x) / len(locations), 2), round(sum(y) / len(locations), 2)]
    for loc in locations:
        loc['centroid'] = centroid
    return locations

loc1 = {
"x_cor" : 10,
"y_cor" : 20}

loc2 = {
"x_cor" : 10,
"y_cor" : 25}

location_list = [loc1,loc2]

print(get_centroid(location_list))
```

**Output**

```
[{'x_cor': 10, 'y_cor': 20, 'centroid': [10.0, 22.5]}, {'x_cor': 10, 'y_cor': 25, 'centroid': [10.0, 22.5]}]
```