# How do I check if the number I enter is in a dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to make this code so it prints out everything in the dictionary, and then the user can pick what dictionary item they want, I would need to be able to use the key they picked and remove it from the dictionary.

```
dict = {'i': [24062, 'txt'], 'e': [10293, 'txt2']}

v = 0
for i in dict
    v += 1
    print(f'({v}) {i}')
v += 1
print(f'({v}) Back')
getinput = int(input('>> '))
if getinput < v and getinput > -1:
# I want it to find the key and value you selected
# I want it to print the key and the value you selected
elif getinput == v:
    print('Go back to menu')
else:
    print('Didnt work :(')
```

Comment: And also side note: bad idea to name your dictionary `dict` in general, as you are basically overwriting a already existing name in python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This approach creates another dictionary (container of `key: value` pairs) `e` with key equal to the index associated with a key from the `d` dictionary and with the value equal to the corresponding key from the `d` dictionary. Given your dictionary above (I am calling it `d`), `e` would be `{0: 'i', 1: 'e'}`: the values represent keys from the `d` dictionary and the keys are the indices of those keys from the `d` dictionary.

The user will then be selecting one of the indices. `e[getinput]` will then provide the associated key of the `d` dictionary.

I hope this helps. Please let me know if there are any questions!

```
d = {'i': [24062, 'txt'], 'e': [10293, 'txt2']}

e = {}
for idx, i in enumerate(d):
    e[idx] = i
    print(f'({idx}) {i}')

idx += 1
print(f'({idx}) back')

# get user input 
getinput = int(input('>> '))
if getinput <= idx - 1 and getinput >= 0:
    print(f"You selected: {e[getinput]}: {d[e[getinput]]}")
elif getinput == idx:
    print('Go back to menu')
else:
    print('Didnt work :(')
```

Example Session:

```
(0) i
(1) e
(2) back
>> 1
You selected: e: [10293, 'txt2']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this. You can convert the dictionary to list and get the key and value according to an index.

```
dict = {'i': [24062, 'txt'], 'e': [10293, 'txt2']}

v = 0
for i in dict:
    v += 1
    print(f'({v}) {i}')
v += 1
print(f'({v}) Back')
getinput = int(input('>> '))

index = getinput -1
if getinput < v and getinput > -1:
    key = list(dict)[index]
    val = list(dict.values())[index]
    print(key, val)

elif getinput == v:
    print('Go back to menu')
else:
    print('Didnt work :(')
```

**Output:**

```
E:\>python test.py
(1) i
(2) e
(3) Back
>> 1
i [24062, 'txt']

E:\>python test.py
(1) i
(2) e
(3) Back
>> 2
e [10293, 'txt2']

E:\>python test.py 3
(1) i
(2) e
(3) Back
>> 3
Go back to menu
```

This below question has further details. [How to index into a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4326658/how-to-index-into-a-dictionary)