# How do I access an item in a dictionary using an index

Tags: python

**input**

```
myDict = {
    "Fast" : "In a Quick Manner",
    "Abhishek" : "A student",
     233 : "Abhishek",
    "a" : ["Abhi","Aka"],
    "b" : [ "abhi",1],
    "hey" : [1,2],
    "hii" : (22, 44, 555),
    "nesteddictionary" : {"RAM":1,"SITA":2,"HANUMAN":3}
print(myDict[1])
print(myDict["nesteddictionary"][0])
```

**output**
nothingg

Comment: Even though Python maintains a deterministic order when iterating over dictionary elements, you can't index into a dictionary by an element's position, as you can with a Python list.  If you really want to access elements according to their position in the dictionary, then keep a list.  The list could replace the dictionary or, if you also need to access the elements by the dictionary key, you could keep both a list of dictionary keys and the existing dictionary.

Comment: *"How do I access an item in a dictionary using an index"* - You can't.   Note that in *some* versions of python, there is no discernible order of the entries in a `dict`.  The deterministic / predictable order only applies in Python 3.7 and later.

Comment: Related: [How to index into a dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4326658/2745495)

Comment: I have a feeling that this is an XY-problem. Why do you think you need to access the dictionary with an index?

Comment: `output nothingg`: I very much doubt that! A key error seems more likely...

Answer (score 0):

The items in a dictionary are not indexed. You must use the key to access the value.
However, if for some reason you need the second key-value pair in your dictionary this is how you do it.

```
myDict = {
    "Fast" : "In a Quick Manner",
    "Abhishek" : "A student",
     233 : "Abhishek",
    "a" : ["Abhi","Aka"],
    "b" : [ "abhi",1],
    "hey" : [1,2],
    "hii" : (22, 44, 555),
    "nesteddictionary" : {"RAM":1,"SITA":2,"HANUMAN":3}}
    
print(myDict[list(myDict.keys())[1]])
print(myDict["nesteddictionary"][list(myDict["nesteddictionary"].keys())[1]])
```

The `list(myDict.keys())[1]` will give you the element at index 1 of the list containing all the keys in the dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

Python dictionary keys are unordered **except** that they exist in the order in which they were added.

The most Pythonic way to handle your problem would be to sub-class UserDict.

Something like this:

```
from collections import UserDict

class Dict(UserDict):
    def __getitem__(self, i):
        key = list(super().keys())[i]
        return super().__getitem__(key)

myDict = {
    "Fast" : "In a Quick Manner",
    "Abhishek" : "A student",
     233 : "Abhishek",
    "a" : ["Abhi","Aka"],
    "b" : [ "abhi",1],
    "hey" : [1,2],
    "hii" : (22, 44, 555),
    "nesteddictionary" : {"RAM":1,"SITA":2,"HANUMAN":3}}

d = Dict(myDict)
print(d[2])
```

**Output:**

```
Abhishek
```

**Note:**

Of course this means that you would not be able to access values by key in the normal way using this class. What you would need to do is reference the UserDict's *data* attribute. For example:

```
print(d.data['b'])
```

**Output:**

```
['abhi', 1]
```

Answer (score -1):

Firstly your print statements has two issues:

- `print(myDict[1])` will raise a KeyError because there's no key called `1` in the dictionary `myDict`.
- Also, for the statement `print(myDict["nesteddictionary"][0])`, python dictionaries don't support indexing by position. So, this will also raise a KeyError.

To be more clear, why can't you use indices with dictionaries?
Because,

- Dictionaries are optimized for looking up values based on unique keys. This allows for very fast (constant-time on average) lookups regardless of the size of the dictionary, which wouldn't be the case if they were indexed like lists.
- Before Python 3.7, dictionaries did not guarantee any specific order of their elements. This means that the order in which items were added to a dictionary might not be the order in which they are stored or retrieved. Starting from Python 3.7, dictionaries maintain the insertion order, but this is more of a side effect of the implementation rather than a core feature of the dictionary data type.

If you find yourself frequently needing to access items by index, you might want to reconsider the data structure you're using. Lists or tuples might be more appropriate if order matters. If you need both key-based access and order-based access, then a combination of data structures or using `OrderedDict` from the collections module might be the solution. This data structure explicitly maintains the order of items.

Answer (score -1):

Dictionaries are unordered collections of key-value pairs

```
myDict = {
    "Fast": "In a Quick Manner",
    "Abhishek": "A student",
    233: "Abhishek",
    "a": ["Abhi", "Aka"],
    "b": ["abhi", 1],
    "hey": [1, 2],
    "hii": (22, 44, 555),
    "nesteddictionary": {"RAM": 1, "SITA": 2, "HANUMAN": 3}
}

# Accessing dictionary items by keys
print(myDict["Fast"])  # Access by string key
print(myDict[233])     # Access by integer key
print(myDict["nesteddictionary"]["RAM"])  # Access nested dictionary item by keys
```

Comment: This does not actually answer the question.