# Order of keys in a different Python dict()

Tags: python, dictionary

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Python dictionary, keep keys/values in same order as declared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867861/python-dictionary-keep-keys-values-in-same-order-as-declared)

If I have in a particular program two different dictionaries with the same keys (but different values), will .keys() be in the same order? I made a few tests and it seems to be the case, but without knowing are how the internals of the dict I am not sure if this is guaranteed.

Thanks,

Comment: Related: [Are keys and values always in the same order](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/835092/python-dictionary-are-keys-and-values-always-the-same-order)

Comment: Thanks but is not a duplicate. I am not asking, if the insertion order is kept (which is not). I am asking if given two dictionaries with the same keys (but maybe different history), the order is the same.

Comment: @bernie - An ordered dictionary is not the same as always ordering the same way. For example, a Java HashMap is in an arbitrary order, but it will always be the same arbitrary order for a particular set of keys.

Comment: I got the answer that I was looking but, the question is not an exact duplicte of "Python dictionary, keep keys/values in same order as declared". I think Brendan Long gave a good example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot rely on the key order at all:

```
>>> {1: None, 9: None}
{1: None, 9: None}
>>> {9: None, 1: None}
{9: None, 1: None}
>>> {1: None, 2: None}
{1: None, 2: None}
>>> {2: None, 1: None}
{1: None, 2: None}
```

Dictionaries are unordered.  In Python 2.7, there is `collections.OrderedDict`, though.

Comment: Python 3.6 dictionaries have keys ordered according to insertion order ... the order in Python 2.7 will produce the same results for the same keys, but is not a defined order.

Comment: @F1Rumors: Even in Python 2.7 the order is not consistent due to hash randomization. And in Pyton 3.6 it is still considered an implementation detail that dicts are ordered – this property was only made part of the interface of dictionaries in Python 3.7.

Comment: @SvenMarnach agreed, you could turn on randomization for 2.7 if you wished

Answer (score 3):

It's not guaranteed by the Python language.

The implementation of the CPython interpreter may have returned keys in the same order in some past versions, but to fix a [security vulnerability](http://bugs.python.org/issue13703) this is very much not-guaranteed in current and future versions.

Comment: The order of keys has always been dependent on insertion order.

Comment: @SvenMarnach Yes, but assuming the same order it was coincidentally identical from one object in one interpreter to another object in the same or different interpreter.   This is no the general case.

Answer (score 2):

The policy of keeping keys/items in the same order does *not* apply between two different dictionary objects and should not be assumed to hold.

Answer (score 1):

If order is important, you should use an `OrderedDict`: http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict . The order of keys in a dictionary can change when key-value pairs are inserted or deleted.

Furthermore, the order can vary between different implementations of the Python language so you cannot rely on the order being the same.

Answer (score 0):

Regular dictionaries in Python are not ordered and you cannot rely on the order of the keys.

In Python 2.7 they introduced OrderedDict. This object stores the keys in the order they were inserted.

If you're using Python 2.6 or less you can have the same functionality by using http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ordereddict