# python 2.6-removing and counting duplicates in a list of dictionaries effeciently

Tags: python

I'm trying to efficiently change:

```
[{'text': 'hallo world', 'num': 1}, 
 {'text': 'hallo world', 'num': 2}, 
 {'text': 'hallo world', 'num': 1}, 
 {'text': 'haltlo world', 'num': 1}, 
 {'text': 'hallo world', 'num': 1}, 
 {'text': 'hallo world', 'num': 1}, 
 {'text': 'hallo world', 'num': 1}]
```

into a list of dictionaries without duplicates and a count of duplicates:

```
[{'text': 'hallo world', 'num': 2, 'count':1}, 
 {'text': 'hallo world', 'num': 1, 'count':5}, 
 {'text': 'haltlo world', 'num': 1, 'count':1}]
```

So far, I have the following to find duplicates:

```
result = [dict(tupleized) for tupleized in set(tuple(item.items()) for item in li)]
```

and it returns:

```
[{'text': 'hallo world', 'num': 2}, 
 {'text': 'hallo world', 'num': 1}, 
 {'text': 'haltlo world', 'num': 1}]
```

THANKS!

Comment: I'd suggest you to use `collections.Counter` but `dict` type is not hashable :(. If you could turn those dicts into dict-like objects with a hash function `Counter` would work nice here.

Comment: you can write your own algorithm based on `set`s. set('ABC')-set(ABC) = set([])

Comment: Thanks. I'm using python 2.6 too. Counter is available for v2.7+

Comment: `tuple(items.items())` won't work properly as the even it the dicts are equal, the `items()` are not always in the same order.

Comment: @gnibbler If each dict has the same keys won't it always be in the same order?

Comment: @jamylak, no it depends on the order the keys are added. I posted an example on SO somewhere - IIRC just 5 keys added in a different order was enough

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9793956/566644) answer for an example.

Comment: @tr33hous What type of data are you storing? Is it just strings and counts (ints) and other immutable types?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'll use one of my favourites from `itertools`:

```
from itertools import groupby

def canonicalize_dict(x):
    "Return a (key, value) list sorted by the hash of the key"
    return sorted(x.items(), key=lambda x: hash(x[0]))

def unique_and_count(lst):
    "Return a list of unique dicts with a 'count' key added"
    grouper = groupby(sorted(map(canonicalize_dict, lst)))
    return [dict(k + [("count", len(list(g)))]) for k, g in grouper]

a = [{'text': 'hallo world', 'num': 1},  
     #....
     {'text': 'hallo world', 'num': 1}]

print unique_and_count(a)
```

Output

```
[{'count': 5, 'text': 'hallo world', 'num': 1}, 
{'count': 1, 'text': 'hallo world', 'num': 2}, 
{'count': 1, 'text': 'haltlo world', 'num': 1}]
```

As gnibbler points out, `d1.items()` and `d2.items()` may have different key-ordering, [even if the keys are identical](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9793956/566644), so I've introduced the `canonical_dict` function to address this concern.

Comment: sorting works if all the keys are sortable. It's possible to be hashable but not sortable - eg complex numbers.

Comment: You have a tiny mistake in `unique_and_count` - it should be `for x in lst` and not `for x in a`.

Comment: @Zaar Thanks, missed that when I refactored the code earlier.

Answer (score 6):

Note: This now uses `frozenset` which means that the items in the dictionary must be hashable.

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> data = [{'text': 'hallo world', 'num': 1}, {'text': 'hallo world', 'num': 2},  {'text': 'hallo world', 'num': 1}, {'text': 'haltlo world', 'num': 1}, {'text': 'hallo world', 'num': 1}, {'text': 'hallo world', 'num': 1}, {'text': 'hallo world', 'num': 1}]
>>> c = defaultdict(int)
>>> for d in data:
        c[frozenset(d.iteritems())] += 1


>>> [dict(chain(k, (('count', count),))) for k, count in c.iteritems()]
[{'count': 1, 'text': 'haltlo world', 'num': 1}, {'count': 1, 'text': 'hallo world', 'num': 2}, {'count': 5, 'text': 'hallo world', 'num': 1}]
```

Comment: Awesome answer. The only caveat is that you need to know the names of the fields before hand. Thanks a lot anyways. Will use solution by @lazyr above.

Comment: @tr33hous You don't need to know them, I was just being explicit I'll change it now

Comment: @tr33hous It doesn't need to know the fields now. Also note that this solution runs in O(N) while lazyr 's solution uses a sort which makes it O(N log N). If you are dealing with huge lists you will need to consider this.

Comment: As gnibbler points out in question comments, `d.iteritems()` isn't guaranteed to return the keys in the same order for all the dictionaries.

Comment: Yeah, just seen the edits. Sorry didn't take more time to look at solution. +1

Comment: @tr33hous I will delete this answer since it is innacurate, unaccept plz or I can't delete it :D

Comment: @jamylak Just borrow my `canonical_dict` function, and it'll work again. No need to delete.

Comment: @jamylak I've made a small change to the function so that it handles unsortable keys (like complex numbers).

Comment: @lazyr Changed to use `frozenset` instead, seems like it's fine since OP is just storint strings in this example.

Comment: @jamylak Yes. But if the values are unhashable, it'll break.

Comment: @lazyr Well he didn't mention any mutables in the example, if so OP can unaccept this anyway.

Comment: @jamylak just removed it as the accepted answer so you can go ahed. Thanks!!

Comment: @tr33house I changed it so it works fine as long as there are no hashables. I'll just leave it now since it works

Answer (score 1):

wanna simple solution without using any builtins,

```
>>> d = [{'text': 'hallo world', 'num': 1}, 
...  {'text': 'hallo world', 'num': 2}, 
...  {'text': 'hallo world', 'num': 1}, 
...  {'text': 'haltlo world', 'num': 1}, 
...  {'text': 'hallo world', 'num': 1}, 
...  {'text': 'hallo world', 'num': 1}, 
...  {'text': 'hallo world', 'num': 1}]
>>> 
>>> def unique_counter(filesets):
...      for i in filesets:
...          i['count'] = sum([1 for j in filesets if j['num'] == i['num']])
...      return {k['num']:k for k in filesets}.values()
... 
>>> unique_counter(d)
[{'count': 6, 'text': 'hallo world', 'num': 1}, {'count': 1, 'text': 'hallo world', 'num': 2}]
```