# List to dict: incorrectly sorted result

Tags: python, sorting

I try to sort this

```python
{1: 2, 3: 4, 4: 3, 2: 1, 0: 0}
```

to this

```python
{3: 4, 4: 3, 1: 2, 2: 1, 0: 0}
```

with *a:b* model where sort by most higher *b* value

```python
import operator

x = {1: 2, 3: 4, 4: 3, 2: 1, 0: 0}
sorted_x = sorted(x.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)

print(sorted_x)
```

First result is good but in list form:

```python
[(3, 4), (4, 3), (1, 2), (2, 1), (0, 0)]
```

And I tried to

```python
print(dict(sorted_x))
```

But…

```python
{0: 0, 1: 2, 2: 1, 3: 4, 4: 3}
```

How I can save correctly sorted result and convert it to the dict format?
Thank you so much

**upd:**

```
OrderedDict([(3, 4), (4, 3), (1, 2), (2, 1), (0, 0)])
```

I cant understand how OrderedDict can solve my problem

Comment: `dict` doesn't maintains order, For that purpose you may use `orderedDict`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Order of keys in a different Python dict()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9793922/order-of-keys-in-a-different-python-dict)

Comment: or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1867861/python-dictionary-keep-keys-values-in-same-order-as-declared

Comment: Before your possible you read question? Posibal'

Comment: @JaroslavNenazvanyi: I read your question! But without orderedDict order depend on Python implementation!

Comment: Another duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15479928/2301450

Comment: Dictionaries are arbitrarily-ordered. If you want to store them in a certain order, you'll need to use a different class like `collections.OrderedDict` as mentioned above.

Comment: I cant understand how convert [(),()] to {,,}. Dict can do it but OrderedDict makes [(),()]

Comment: `[(),()]` is just the representation of `OrderedDict`

Comment: I need to write into file without any representations. My question is about how to avoid this

Comment: *I cant understand how OrderedDict can solve my problem* - Your problem is that you don't know how to get a sorted/ordered `dict`. The answer is "you can't". However, `OrderedDict` is a subclass of `dict`, which *can* keep the key:value pairs in the order you need.

Comment: You mean `for key in`…?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand

Comment: Iterations or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> sorted_dict = OrderedDict()
>>> dct = {1: 2, 3: 4, 4: 3, 2: 1, 0: 0}
>>> dct.values().sort()
>>> for x in sorted(dct.values(), reverse=True):
...     keys = [idx for idx in dct if dct[idx]==x]
...     for key in keys:
...         sorted_dict[key] = x
... 
>>> 
>>> sorted_dict
OrderedDict([(3, 4), (4, 3), (1, 2), (2, 1), (0, 0)])
>>>
```

or if you are dead set on writing something that looks like dict syntax to a file,

```
>>> def print_dict_looking_thing(ordered_dict):
...     print "{"
...     for key, value in ordered_dict.iteritems():
...         print "{0}: {1},".format(key, value)
...     print "}"
... 
>>> print_dict_looking_thing(sorted_dict)
{
3: 4,
4: 3,
1: 2,
2: 1,
0: 0,
}
```

That is how OrderedDict "solves your problem".  But, a few points worth reemphasizing:

1. Dicts are unordered.  You can't "sort them", only operate on their keys and values.
2. OrderedDicts remember the order that items were added.
3. It sounds like you are trying to print to a file something that looks like dict syntax.  If you do that and read the dict into python at some point, *it will become an unordered object (a dict) again*.
4. It is not super clear what "your problem" is.  What is the desired end state; printing a string that reads like dict syntax?  Making something that has the accessor methods that dicts do?  Clarifying what exactly you want (in terms of performance) would be helpful.
5. The code above has O(n**2) complexity.  Don't use it on big things.

Answer (score 0):

Dictionary can't be ordered. But you can use class `collections.OrderedDict`.