# Remove duplicates from a list of dictionaries when only one of the key values is different

Tags: python

I have seen some similar answers, but I can't find something specific for this case:

I have a list of dictionaries like this:

```
[
 {"element":Bla, "version":2, "date":"12/04/12"},
 {"element":Bla, "version":2, "date":"12/05/12"},
 {"element":Bla, "version":3, "date":"12/04/12"}
]
```

The actual dictionary has many other keys, but what I'm trying to do is to delete all the entries that have the exact same key pair values, except for the date. That is, to delete all duplicates (which are not really exact duplicates as only the date varies). In this case, what I would expect to get is:

```
[
 {"element":Bla, "version":2, "date":"12/04/12"},
 {"element":Bla, "version":3, "date":"12/04/12"}
]
```

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, I was a bit stuck. Another question though, how would you do it to only keep the latest date, given that the date was a date time object?

Comment: If you don't need the dictionaries in order they are in the initial list, you can do it with nearly the same algorithm, but instead of `result=[]` you will have `result={}` containing pairs `h: d` and you will need to update `result` of `h` is missing or new `d` has newer date. You won't need `seen` here, as its role will be served by `result`. Though you will loose the order. If you need order, you will have to make 2 pass. The first one to gather the newest dates, and the second to build the ordered list.

Comment: I used the same solution but just sorted the list before running the duplicate finder snippet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You say you have a lot of other keys in the dictionary not mentioned in the question.

Here is `O(n)` algorithm to do what you need:

```
>>> seen = set()
>>> result = []
>>> for d in dicts:
...     h = d.copy()
...     h.pop('date')
...     h = tuple(h.items())
...     if h not in seen:
...         result.append(d)
...         seen.add(h)

>>> pprint(result)
[{'date': '12/04/12', 'element': 'Bla', 'version': 2},
 {'date': '12/04/12', 'element': 'Bla', 'version': 3}]
```

`h` is a copy of the dict. `date` key is removed from it with `pop`.

Then `tuple` is created as a hashable type which can be added to `set`.

If `h` has never been seen before, we append it to `result` and add to `seen`. Additions to `seen` is `O(1)` as well as lookups (`h not in seen`).

At the end, `result` contains only unique elements in terms of defined `h` values.

Comment: I guess you should sort the `h.items()`

Comment: Sorry, in you example, seen is a list?  Doesn't let me add a tuple to a list, but if append it works.

Comment: @thkang Not necessarily. `h.items()` will return the same sequences for the same `h`s.

Comment: @user443850 Sorry, I forgot to copy all the initialization from the IDLE. Now I edited the answer.

Comment: I now get: TypeError, unhashable type: "list", on if h not in seen

Comment: @user443850 Do you have any other data apart from strings in the initial dictionary?

Comment: @user443850 Is `Bla` an object?

Comment: Yes, integers and datetime objects. However, setting seen as a list works as well. There are also tuples and other types.

Comment: @user443850 Something inside the dict hinders hashing. And `set` is worked with hashable data.

Comment: @user443850 `int` are perfectly hashable. `datetime` are also hashable (I have just checked). You can check it yourself with `hash(x)` (use whatever you want to check in the place of `x`)

Comment: @user443850 If you set `seen` as list, you will get `O(n^2)` algorithm, which is much slower, as list is searched through from beginning to the end each time `in seen` is used. If `seen` is `set`, `in seen` is constant time operation `O(1)`.

Comment: I think I can live with the performance hit, as it is not a huge data set. Thanks for your help again.I do have tuples and lists in the dictionary.

Comment: @user443850 Your are welcome! If you get sometimes concerned with the performance, just make an analysis what hinders you from hashing dicts (with `hash(d)`), and then just convert it to hashable structure, as `h` is just to remove repetitions, and it should correspond to `d` (just to determine `d`s equivalence) but not to be exactly the same.

Comment: A tuple is only hashable if all the elements contained in it are also hashable.

Comment: @drewk Yes! From the comments I can't see which is unhashable (int, stirng, datetime are all hashable).

Comment: I just found a problem with this method. h.items can returns different list orders each time, so the loop does not detect the tuple as a duplicate. Any ideas?

Comment: @user443850 Please, give an example of this not-expected behaviour.

Comment: @user443850 [This answer]( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/835092/python-dictionary-are-keys-and-values-always-the-same-order) claims that non-modified dict should iterate items in the same order. Still, you lists are produced from different dicts, and though the resultant dicts may be effectively the same, the corresponding lists may have different order. So, just sort the items before adding to `tuple`. Try this: `tuple(sorted(h.items()))`

Comment: What if you want the latest date only for each duplicated item?

Answer (score 3):

You could use the "`unique_everseen`" [recipe](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) from [`itertools`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) to create a new `list`.

```
list(unique_everseen(original_list, key=lambda e: '{element}@{version}'.format(**e)))
```

If your "key" needs to be wider than the `lambda` I have written (to accomodate more values), then it's probably worth extracting to a function:

```
def key_without_date(element):
    return '@'.join(["{}".format(v) for k,v in element.iteritems() if k != 'date'])

list(unique_everseen(original_list, key=key_without_date))
```

Answer (score 1):

Apologies for terrible variable names. There is probably a cleaner way but this should work

```
seen = {(item["element"], item["version"]): False for item in mylist}

output = []
for item in mylist:
    item_key = (item["element"], item["version"])
    if not seen[item_key]:
        output.append(item)
        seen[item_key] = True
```

Answer (score 1):

Pandas can solve this quickly:

```
import pandas as pd
Bla = "Bla"
d = [
{"element":Bla, "version":2, "date":"12/04/12"},
{"element":Bla, "version":2, "date":"12/05/12"},
{"element":Bla, "version":3, "date":"12/04/12"}
]
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
df[~df.drop("date", axis=1).duplicated()]
```

output:

```
       date element  version
0  12/04/12     Bla        2
2  12/04/12     Bla        3
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
LoD=[
{"element":'Bla', "version":2, 'list':[1,2,3], "date":"12/04/12"},
{"element":'Bla', "version":2, 'list':[1,2,3], "date":"12/05/12"},
{"element":'Bla', "version":3, 'list':[1,2,3], "date":"12/04/12"}
]

LoDcopy=[]
seen=set()


for d in LoD:
    dc=d.copy()
    del dc['date']
    s=dc.__str__()
    if s in seen: continue
    seen.add(s)
    LoDcopy.append(d)    

print LoDcopy
```

prints:

```
[{'date': '12/04/12', 'version': 2, 'list': [1, 2, 3], 'element': 'Bla'}, 
 {'date': '12/04/12', 'version': 3, 'list': [1, 2, 3], 'element': 'Bla'}]
```