# Remove duplicates key from list of dictionaries python

Tags: python

I am trying to remove the duplicates from following list:

```
distinct_cur = [
    {'rtc': 0, 'vf': 0, 'mtc': 0, 'doc': 'good job', 'foc': 195, 'st': 0.0, 'htc': 2, '_id': ObjectId('58e86a550a0aeff4e14ca6bb'), 'ftc': 0}, 
    {'rtc': 0, 'vf': 0, 'mtc': 0, 'doc': 'good job', 'foc': 454, 'st': 0.8, 'htc': 1, '_id': ObjectId('58e8d03958ae6d179c2b4413'), 'ftc': 1},
    {'rtc': 0, 'vf': 2, 'mtc': 1, 'doc': 'test', 'foc': 45, 'st': 0.8, 'htc': 12, '_id': ObjectId('58e8d03958ae6d180c2b4446'), 'ftc': 0}
]
```

Of dictionaries based on condition that if 'doc' key value text is same then one of the dictionary should be removed. I have tried the following solution:

```
distinct_cur = [dict(y) for y in set(tuple(x.items()) for x in cur)]
```

But duplicates are still present in the final list.

Below is the desired output as in 1st and 2nd distinct_cur text of key 'doc' value is same (good job):

```
[
    {'rtc': 0, 'vf': 0, 'mtc': 0, 'doc': 'good job', 'foc': 195, 'st': 0.0, 'htc': 2, '_id': ObjectId('58e86a550a0aeff4e14ca6bb'), 'ftc': 0}, 
    {'rtc': 0, 'vf': 2, 'mtc': 1, 'doc': 'test', 'foc': 45, 'st': 0.8, 'htc': 12, '_id': ObjectId('58e8d03958ae6d180c2b4446'), 'ftc': 0}
]
```

Comment: It would be better if you could provide a sample output.

Comment: You're not allowed to use duplicate keys in dictionary. What you mean by removing duplicate key? what should be removed?

Comment: So after you find dictionaries with same `doc` key, how you decide which one should be removed?

Comment: Here are some similar questions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15511903/remove-duplicates-from-a-list-of-dictionaries-when-only-one-of-the-key-values-is and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9427163/remove-duplicate-dict-in-list-in-python

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You're creating a `set` out of different elements and expect that it will remove the duplicates based on a criterion that only you know.

You have to iterate through your list, and add to the result list only if `doc` has a different value than the previous ones:
for instance like this:

```
done = set()
result = []
for d in distinct_cur:
    if d['doc'] not in done:
        done.add(d['doc'])  # note it down for further iterations
        result.append(d)
```

that will keep only the first occurrence(s) of the dictionaries which have the same `doc` key by registering the known keys in an auxiliary set.

Another possibility is to use a dictionary with the key as the `"doc"` key of the dictionary, iterating backwards in the list so the first items overwrite the last ones in the list:

```
result = list({i['doc']:i for i in reversed(distinct_cur)}.values())
```

Comment: The `result` object in the second solution will be of type `dict_values`. You need to convert it to `list` type using `list()` function.

Comment: you're right. Editing it in

Answer (score 5):

I see 2 similar solutions that depend on your domain problem: do you want to keep the *first* instance of a key or the *last* instance?

Using the *last* (so as to overwrite the previous matches) is simpler:

```
d = {r['doc']: r for r in distinct_cur}.values()
```

Answer (score 3):

One liner to deduplicate the list of dictionaries `distinct_cur` on the primary_key of `doc`

```
[i for n, i in enumerate(distinct_cur) if i.get('doc') not in [y.get('doc') for y in distinct_cur[n + 1:]]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
distinct_cur  =[dict(t) for t in set([tuple(d.items()) for d in distinct_cur])]
```

Worked for me...