# Is there a way to filter a list of dictionaries based on a value in one dictionary being less than the same key in another?

Tags: python, dictionary, filter, list-comprehension

I apologize for the convoluted title. I need to filter a list of dictionaries by a fairly specific criteria.

Normally, I would do a list comprehension, but I'm not positive on the logic.

Here's an example list:

```
list_dict = [{'item_id': '000354', 'ts_created': '11/12/2013', 'item_desc': 'a product'},
             {'item_id': '000354', 'ts_created': '11/13/2013', 'item_desc': 'a product'},
             {'item_id': '000355', 'ts_created': '11/12/2013', 'item_desc': 'a different product'}]
```

You'll notice that the first two dictionary items are identical besides 'ts_created'.

I want to create a new dictionary keeping all items with the earliest timestamp, and discarding the rest.

Edit: Removed 'elegantly' from title as it seemed to offend some.

Edit 2: Tried to improve title.

Edit 3 (focus?): I'm really not sure how to focus this question anymore than it already is,  but I'll try. In reference to the example code above (the actual list is much greater), There are duplicate dictionaries within the list. The only difference in them is the 'ts_created' values. I want to only keep the unique 'item_id' dictionaries, and further the earliest 'ts_created'. The resulting list would look like this.

```
list_dict = [{'item_id': '000354', 'ts_created': '11/12/2013', 'item_desc': 'a product'},
             {'item_id': '000355', 'ts_created': '11/12/2013', 'item_desc': 'a different product'}]
```

Comment: Please edit your not-elegant-enough-for-your-tastes code into your question as a [mre]. And my advice is if you’re not confident about list comprehensions or generator expressions then simply write them as for loops - using for loops means you can debug or add print statements to see what’s happening, neither of which is possible in one-liners.

Comment: Hi ZombieDev, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please help me understand the requirements a little better. Is the goal to return the dictionary from the list of dictionaries with the earliest `ts_created` date? And if there are multiple dictionaries with the same earliest `ts_created` date, to return them as a list of dictionaries?

Comment: Does this answer your question? First sort using `ts_created` and then remove duplicates. Step 1. [How do I sort a list of dictionaries by a value of the dictionary?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72899/1431750) Step 2. [Remove duplicates from a list of dictionaries when only one of the key values is different](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15511903/remove-duplicates-from-a-list-of-dictionaries-when-only-one-of-the-key-values-is)

Comment: Edited my question to improve clarity. @aneroid Those links are very helpful! Essentially, breaking them down, sorting, and then constructing a new list of dictionaries. Thank you for your help.

Comment: You're welcome. And welcome to StackOverflow. One of the requirements of a good question which will get answers is to **post code of what you have tried** and not just "this is what I have, this is what I want, go do it for me", even if you didn't mean to. Glad those two links (steps) helped. While trying a solution, if you run into a specific problem, post another question or edit this one. PS. I closed it as a **duplicate** question of 1/2 I linked.

Answer (score 0):

You can filter the dictionaries using a dictionary of dictionaries keyed on the item_id.  As you populate that indexes dictionary, only keep the items that have thegreatest timestamp.   Since your time stamps are strings not formatted in the international standard you will need to convert them to actual dates to compare them.  A second dictionary (indexed on the item_id as well) can be used to keep track of the converted timestamps.

```
list_dict = [{'item_id': '000354', 'ts_created': '11/12/2013', 'item_desc': 'a product'},
             {'item_id': '000354', 'ts_created': '11/13/2013', 'item_desc': 'a product'},
             {'item_id': '000355', 'ts_created': '11/12/2013', 'item_desc': 'a different product'}]

from datetime import datetime
maxDates = dict()  # association between item and timestamp
result   = dict()  # indexed single instance result (dictionary of dictionaries)
for d in list_dict:
    key       = d['item_id']
    timestamp = datetime.strptime(d['ts_created'], '%m/%d/%Y') # usable timestamp
    if itemId not in result or timestamp>maxDates[key]:        # keep only latest
        result[key]   = d
        maxDates[key] = timestamp
result = list(result.values())    # convert back to a list of dictionaries

print(result)
        
[{'item_id': '000354', 'ts_created': '11/13/2013', 'item_desc': 'a product'},
 {'item_id': '000355', 'ts_created': '11/12/2013', 'item_desc': 'a different product'}]
```

If uniqueness is determined by multiple fields (as opposed to just the item_id), you will need to combine all the values into a single key.

For example (for all fields except the time stamp):

```
key = tuple(d[k] for k in sorted(d) if k != 'ts_created')
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `pandas.DataFrame`, order by date and then drop all the duplicates.

```py
import pandas

df = pandas.DataFrame(list_dict)
# To datetime
df['ts_created'] = pandas.to_datetime(df['ts_created'])
# Sort by item_id, then by date
df.sort_values(by=['item_id', 'ts_created'], inplace=True)
# Drop duplicates, leaving only the first item_id
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['item_id'], keep='first', inplace=True)
# Convert the dates back to the original format
df['ts_created'] = df.ts_created.dt.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')
# Create the list again
df.to_dict(orient='records')
```