# Converting tuples to multiple indices in a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I'm starting with a dictionary like this:

```
dict = {(100000550L, u'ActivityA'): {'bar__sum': 14.0, 'foo__sum': 12.0},
        (100001799L, u'ActivityB'): {'bar__sum': 7.0, 'foo__sum': 3.0}}
```

Which, when converted to a DataFrame, puts as column headers the tuples of (id, activitytype):

```
df = DataFrame(dict).transpose()

                        bar__sum  foo__sum
(100000550, ActivityA)        14        12
(100001799, ActivityB)         7         3
```

How can I convert the tuples in the index to a MultiIndex? Ie, so that the end result looks like this instead:

```
                        bar__sum  foo__sum
id        act_type
100000550 ActivityA        14        12
100001799 ActivityB         7         3
```

What's the best way to do this? Is there some option on the DataFrame creation that I'm missing? Or should it happen via a list comprehension, which feels inefficient to me.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

If you want to **convert index** of your dataframe:

```
>>> df.index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df.index)
>>> df
                     bar__sum  foo__sum
100000550 ActivityA        14        12
100001799 ActivityB         7         3

>>> df.index.names = ['id', 'act_type']
>>> df
                     bar__sum  foo__sum
id        act_type                     
100000550 ActivityA        14        12
100001799 ActivityB         7         3
```

You can also create DataFrame **directly from dictionary** (`d` is your dict, don't call your variable `dict` since it'll shadow standard python dictionary):

```
>>> pd.DataFrame(d.values(), index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(d.keys(), names=['id', 'act_type']))
                     bar__sum  foo__sum
id        act_type                     
100001799 ActivityB         7         3
100000550 ActivityA        14        12
```

Note that `values()` and `keys()` are [always in the same order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835092/python-dictionary-are-keys-and-values-always-the-same-order), so no worries about that.

Comment: Nice trick passing only `d.values()` as the argument!  I was trying to figure out something to get access to the post-sorted index after passing `d`, but this way you don't need it at all.

Comment: using Python 3.6 and pandas 0.23.1 `d.values()` isn't an acceptable data type to create the dataframe. If you cast `d.values` to a list it fixes the issue. `pd.DataFrame(list(d.values()), index=pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(d.keys(), names=['id', 'act_type']))` should do the trick