# Using pythons dictionary's to create a generic MySQL insert string

Tags: python, mysql, sql, dictionary, insert

I would like to write a generic SQL command that could take in its data from a Dictionary. This way I can simply pass a dictionary into a function and get that data on to a MySQL server.

Example:

```
dict = {'table':'test_table','dataA':dataValue1,'dataB':dataValue2, ect}

cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO %(table)s (%(columName1)s,%(columName2)s,ect)
VALUES (%(dataA)s,%(dataB)s)""", dict)
```

Something like that. I also need the command to support dictionary's of different length. The idea is that as long as said tables exist all of my data gets inserted without having to write out a pile of SQL querys.

Any one have a clean way of going about this or perhaps some reading I could do to solve this problem ?

Comment: Do you know the column names?

Comment: yes, I could write a bit of code to create the tables if they dont exist but thats not what I am getting at here so I didnt want to complicate the issue. for the sake of example lets say the database is all setup and the column names are 'dataA and 'dataB'

Comment: I would like to be able to pass in the column names too. so suppose the next dict only had 'dataC' and 'dataD' I would want this to still work. (supposing that dataC and D also already exist)

Comment: Okay, I understand that you want to build that query programmatically? What have you tried so far?

Comment: several variations of what you see above. I am having trouble nailing down the proper syntax for passing in all the variables so that SQL will accept it. I can build the string but nothing I try seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation for the `MySQLdb` module is located [here on sourceforge](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html). Under the "Functions and attributes" subheading, while discussing the `paramstyle` attribute, you can find:

> Parameter placeholders can **only** be used to insert column values. They can **not** be used for other parts of SQL, such as table names, statements, etc.

So, you won't be able to use the module's `execute` method in the way that you showed in your example.

Another limitation of the `execute` method is that you need a `%s` placeholder everywhere you want to insert a parameterized column value. So, if you want an indefinite number of values, you need an indefinite number of placeholders. You could write a function like this:

```
def prepareinsert(mydict):
    query = """
    INSERT INTO {0} ({1}) VALUES ({2});
    """
    d = dict(mydict)  # don't modify the input dictionary if you want to reuse it
    table = d.pop('table')
    columns = ','.join(d.keys())
    placeholders = ','.join(['%s'] * len(d))
    values = d.values()
    return (query.format(table, columns, placeholders), values)
```

This gives you the two elements that `execute` wants - a query at minimum, and if the query has `%s` placeholders, a sequence or mapping object that contains the desired parameters.

Note that `mydict` is guaranteed to return the keys and values in the same order, as long as it's not altered in the meantime (see: [Python dictionary: are keys() and values() always the same order?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/835092/2359271))

You might use this function in the following manner:

```
input = {'table':'favorite_actors', 'columnA':'Brent', 'columnB':'Spiner'}
query, params = prepareinsert(input)
cursor.execute(query, params)
```

Of course, you still need to know that your input is correct.

Comment: Thank you. This is setting me up with the right line of thinking. Just  use a function to build the string bit by bit until I have a proper query. I do have complete control over my inputs so I can get those sorted too.

Comment: @user3482234 It'll do what you asked for, but I make no claims about whether this is really the best approach for whatever you're doing more generally. ;)

Comment: for the moment I just need it to work. I can worry about coming up with clever ways to optimize the code later.