# Jinja2 not respecting dict ordering

Tags: python, dictionary, jinja2

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835092/python-dictionary-are-keys-and-values-always-the-same-order), If items(), keys(), values(),  iteritems(), iterkeys(), and  itervalues() are called with no intervening modifications to the dictionary, the lists will directly correspond.

However in Jinja2 this seems not to be the case, as keys() and values() are giving different orders for me. I'm trying to build a table as follows:

```
   {% for record in records %}
        {% if loop.first %}
            <tr>
            {% for key in record.keys() %}
                <th>{{ key }}</th>
            {% endfor %}
            </tr>
        {% endif %}
        <tr>
        {% for value in record.values() %}
            <td>{{ value }}</td>
        {% endfor %}
        </tr>
    {% endfor %}
```

and currently the values don't correspond to the keys. Anyone else come across this?

Comment: have not. as workaround:  does using  `record.items()` and then selecting the key or the value help? or did you  consider using an `OrderedDict`?

Comment: OrderedDict solved it thanks

Answer (score 0):

Seems the problem was actually with `psycopg.extras.DictCursor2`. In the end I used an `OrderedDict` as suggested by hiro.