# Combine values from 2 dicts into a np.array python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, dictionary

I have two dicts

```
a = {0:[1,2,3,4], 1:[5,6,7,8],...}
b = {0:[4,3,2,1], 1:[8,7,6,5],...}
```

I would like to create an `np.array c` for each key-value pair such as follows

```
c1 = array([[1,4],[2,3],[3,2],[4,1]])
c2 = array([[5,8],[6,7],[7,6],[8,5]])
```

How can I do this? Is it possible to store np.array in a python dict so that I can create a single dict `c` instead of multiple arrays

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can put `np.array` into a Python dictionary. Just use a [dict comprehension](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) and [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#zip) the lists from `a` and `b` together.

```
>>> a = {0:[1,2,3,4], 1:[5,6,7,8]}
>>> b = {0:[4,3,2,1], 1:[8,7,6,5]}
>>> c = {i: np.array(list(zip(a[i], b[i]))) for i in set(a) & set(b)}
>>> c
{0: array([[1, 4], [2, 3], [3, 2], [4, 1]]),
 1: array([[5, 8], [6, 7], [7, 6], [8, 5]])}
```

Comment: Wow. Thank you so much. Works elegantly

Answer (score 2):

You can also use `column_stack` with a list comprehension:

```
import numpy as np

[np.column_stack((a[k], b[k])) for k in b.keys()]

Out[30]:
[array([[1, 4],
        [2, 3],
        [3, 2],
        [4, 1]]), array([[5, 8],
        [6, 7],
        [7, 6],
        [8, 5]])]
```

Comment: This method is almost twice as fast than using a dictionaray. Thank you so much

Comment: you are welcome! Certainly because I turned around `zip` (but you can use `izip` from `itertools`)

Comment: Does `b.keys()` guarantee that the keys come out in sorted (or any specific) order?

Comment: Answer is there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/835092/python-dictionary-are-keys-and-values-always-the-same-order

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel That was not the question, but whether it's possible that the resulting array ends up as `[c2, c1]` instead of `[c1, c2]`. Using a dict with 100 keys being random numbers from 1 to 1000, `keys()` seems to return the keys in random order (Python 2 and 3).