# Why is the order of dict and dict.items() different?

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary, ipython

```
>>> d = {'A':1, 'b':2, 'c':3, 'D':4}

>>> d
{'A': 1, 'D': 4, 'b': 2, 'c': 3}

>>> d.items()
[('A', 1), ('c', 3), ('b', 2), ('D', 4)]
```

Does the order get randomized twice when I call d.items()? Or does it just get randomized differently? Is there any alternate way to make d.items() return the same order as d?

Edit: Seems to be an IPython thing where it auto sorts the dict. Normally dict and dict.items() should be in the same order.

Comment: A dict doesn't have an inherent order, the specific order of its elements is an implementation detail and depends on the history of the dict. If order matters, use an ordered dict. If it doesn't matter, don't rely on it.

Comment: The order of d.keys() and d.items() will match though ([ref](http://stackoverflow.com/q/835092/2285236))

Comment: Can't reproduce. Both `d` and `d.items()` show up in the same order when I try it. Are you sure these were actually the same dict in your test? Are you sure you didn't do anything to the dict between the statements shown?

Comment: Were the lines you show in the question all run in the same interpreter session? Recent versions of Python randomize the hashes of strings so the order you'll see the keys in a dictionary (even one created exactly the same way) will differ between sessions.

Comment: @user2357112 I can reproduce: http://i.imgur.com/qsX5lAK.png (Python 3.5.2)

Comment: @ayhan: Strange. I wonder if that's an IPython thing.

Comment: Further testing seems to indicate this is an IPython-specific thing.

Comment: Incidentally, if you ran this through IPython and then edited the output to look like a regular Python interactive session, please don't do that. It makes it much harder to help you when a problem turns out to be IPython-specific.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You seem to have tested this on IPython. IPython uses its own specialized pretty-printing facilities for various types, and the pretty-printer for dicts sorts the keys before printing (if possible). The `d.items()` call doesn't sort the keys, so the output is different.

In an ordinary Python session, the order of the items in the dict's `repr` would match the order of the items from the `items` method. Dict iteration order is supposed to be stable as long as a dict isn't modified. (This guarantee is not explicitly extended to the dict's `repr`, but it would be surprising if the implicit iteration in `repr` broke consistency with other forms of dict iteration.)

Comment: Yeah this was an IPython issue.

Comment: `%pprint = False` should turn it off.