# how to iterate through keys and values in a dictionary in python

Tags: python

I have created a dictionary which has data like this:

```
0 = {'Input_file': 'Sample_ Data.xlsx', 'Column_Name': 'Status', 'Column_Filter': 'Active'}

1 = {'Input_file': 'Sample_ Data.xlsx', 'Column_Name': 'Status', 'Column_Filter': 'Inactive'}
```

how can I iterate through only the values in the same order as 0 and 1 without the keys getting printed. I want to read :-  `Sample_Data.xlsx , Status, Active` in the first iteration and `Sample_Data.xlsx , Status, Inactive` in the second.

Below is the code I am using to print.

```
my_dict = reference.to_dict('index')
for column,values in my_dict.items():
    print("{} = {}".format(column, values))
```

Comment: `my_dict.keys()` and `my_dict.values()` do pretty much what you would think they do ...

Comment: That looks like you actually have a nested dictionary where the outer dictionary has only one key and the value is another dictionary (which you then get when calling `values` on the outer dictionary).

Comment: Well if you are concerned with the order then my_dict.values() is not for you. You need to get the keys and iterate the dictionaries using keys.

Comment: Also, the order of `dict.keys()` and `dict.values()` is the same if you don't modify the dictionary between the calls: https://stackoverflow.com/a/835430/4042267

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `list(dict.keys())` to get the keys as a list. As [N_tro_P](https://stackoverflow.com/users/318800/n-tro-p) pointed out, you can use `sorted(dict.keys())` to get keys in sorted order and iterate with that.

Answer (score 0):

There is no guaranteed "order" for dictionary. However, since both dictionaries have the same keys you could cycle through one and use the key against both (or other dictionaries as well). When you "iterate" a dictionary in Python you get the key. Use the key to access the values of the "other" dictionaries.

```
for keys in my_dict
   print(my_dict[key])
   print(my_other_dict[key])
```