# Create, mix, and match any dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a input data

```
block = {
    'kernel' : [3,5,7],
    'strides' : [2,3],
    'padding': ['same'],
    'activation':['relu'],
    'type':['conv'],
}
```

I would like to create a mix and match follow:

```
[ {'kernel': 3 ,'strides' : 2, 'padding': 'same', 'activation': 'relu', 'type': 'conv'}, 
  {'kernel': 3 ,'strides' : 3, 'padding': 'same', 'activation': 'relu', 'type': 'conv'}, 
  {'kernel': 5 ,'strides' : 2, 'padding': 'same', 'activation': 'relu', 'type': 'conv'}, 
  {'kernel': 5 ,'strides' : 3, 'padding': 'same', 'activation': 'relu', 'type': 'conv'}, 
  {'kernel': 7 ,'strides' : 2, 'padding': 'same', 'activation': 'relu', 'type': 'conv'}, 
  {'kernel': 7 ,'strides' : 3, 'padding': 'same', 'activation': 'relu', 'type': 'conv'}]
```

Comment: what is `count` and `hyperparam`? If `activation` has another item in the list are there even more possibilities?

Comment: Hello, Chakkrit, I've never had to do this, the answer they gave you looks pythonic and simple. Next time you do a question, try and describe a little bit more, your problem, considering the data structures you use, and what you've tried, that could help anyone that answers, more, because they don't need to analyze a bunch of code as deep, and instead worry more about, the concept that the explain. Great question, and Welcome.

Comment: **How** does it not work? Any error messages?

Comment: @ekiim Thank you so much, Next time, I will be doing to your recommendation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) to generate the combinations of values, then build those back into dictionaries:

```
from itertools import product

keys, possible_values = zip(*block.items())

res = [dict(zip(keys, vals)) for vals in product(*possible_values)]
print(res)
```

prints

```
[{'kernel': 3, 'strides': 2, 'padding': 'same', 'activation': 'relu', 'type': 'conv'}, 
 {'kernel': 3, 'strides': 3, 'padding': 'same', 'activation': 'relu', 'type': 'conv'}, 
 {'kernel': 5, 'strides': 2, 'padding': 'same', 'activation': 'relu', 'type': 'conv'}, 
 {'kernel': 5, 'strides': 3, 'padding': 'same', 'activation': 'relu', 'type': 'conv'}, 
 {'kernel': 7, 'strides': 2, 'padding': 'same', 'activation': 'relu', 'type': 'conv'}, 
 {'kernel': 7, 'strides': 3, 'padding': 'same', 'activation': 'relu', 'type': 'conv'}]
```

Comment: `keys, possible_values = zip(*block.items())` looks redundant when we have `dict.keys`/`dict.values` methods

Comment: @AzatIbrakov I can never remember if `keys()` and `values()` have the same order.  [It looks like they do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835092/python-dictionary-are-keys-and-values-always-the-same-order), so you're right that would be better