# Loop over multiple generators of multiple values

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, dictionary, generator

I am trying to go through all elements of two given dictionaries to make sure they are equal, and if not I want the name of the property where they differ.

Here is my basic approach:

```
# Dictionnaries
v1 = { "a" : { "b" : 1, "c" : 2 }, "d" : { "e" : { "f" : 3 }}}
v2 = { "a" : { "b" : 1, "c" : 2 }, "d" : { "e" : { "f" : 4 }}}

def gen(k, v):
    if type(v) is dict:
        for k in v:
            yield from gen(k, v[k])
    else:
        yield k, v

# Used alone the generator works as expected:
for k, v in gen("root", v1):
    print("{}: {}".format(k, v))
```

My problem is that I want to compare the two dictionaries, from what I could gather it should look like this:

```
for k1, v1, k2, v2 in zip(gen("root1", v1), gen("root2", v2)):
    print("{}: {}".format(k1, v1))
    print("{}: {}".format(k2, v2))
    print("===========")
```

The interpreter says only two values are returned, so I assumed this would work (and it does):

```
for t1, t2 in zip(gen("root1", v1), gen("root2", v2)):
    print("{}: {}".format(t1[0], t1[1]))
    print("{}: {}".format(t2[0], t2[1]))
    print("===========")
```

### My question:

It might be purely preferential, but I really wonder

1. How I can get the first loop to work, so that I don't have to use the brackets all the time?
2. I tried to unpack with `*`, but no success. Why can't I do `zip(*gen(...), *gen(...))`?

(By the way I know I could just add `k1, v1, k2, v2 = *t1, *t2` at the beginning of the loop, I'm just looking for a nicer solution)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can unpack each returned tuple as follows:

```
for (k1, val1), (k2, val2) in zip(gen('root1', v1), gen('root2', v2)):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question was more specific to syntax, but there are some things you might want to consider:

1. dictionaries are unordered collections, so that comparison might fail even if those dicts are identical just because they were iterated over in a different order.
2. Python does not have [Tail Call Optimization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/310974/what-is-tail-call-optimization), so for sufficiently nested dicts, that code will fail with stack overflow.

If you want to visually compare dicts, here is a solution that takes care of these issues.

Assumption: structure of the dicts is the same (keys are the same, if a value for 1 is a dict, it will be a dict for the other one, those keys can't be iterables of other types, e.g. lists).

```
from collections import deque

def gen(dct1, dct2):
    q = deque()
    q.append(("root", dct1, dct2))
    while q:
        k, d1, d2 = q.pop()
        for key in d1:  # assuming the same keys for both dicts
            val1 = d1[key]
            val2 = d2[key]

            # assuming that if the structure is the same -> if val1 is a dict, val2 is a dict as well 
            if isinstance(val1, dict): 
                q.append((k, val1, val2)) 
            else:
                yield key, val1, val2

for k, val1, val2 in gen(v1, v2):
    print("{}: {}".format(k, val1))
    print("{}: {}".format(k, val2))
    print("===========")
```

Comment: The structure is not guaranteed to be the same, also from this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835092/python-dictionary-are-keys-and-values-always-the-same-order I gather that what you are saying isn't exactly true, this being said instead of `for k in v` I can simply do `for k in sorted(v)`