# Randomly choose a dict key, with a greater chance of selection, based off its value

Tags: python-3.x

So I'm trying to help a friend out with a solution where people donate to a cause and randomly get selected. The problem is, the more you donate, the greater the chance you have of being selected.

Say I have a dictionary of people:

```
people = {
    "Mike":0,
    "Mark":4,
    "Zach":2,
    "Bryan":2,
    "Eddie":1
    "Erin":0,
}
```

Is there a way that a person can be randomly picked from this dictonary, but based on their value, give them a greater chance of winning?

Answer (score 2):

`random` module has a `choices` method that takes weights (it returns a list of `k=1` by default, so take the first item):

```
import random

print(random.choices(list(people.keys()), weights=people.values())[0])
```

(in case you wonder, as I did, if `keys()` and `values()` are in matching order, they are. See [Python dictionary: are keys() and values() always the same order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835092/python-dictionary-are-keys-and-values-always-the-same-order))

See in action here: https://repl.it/repls/AmbitiousVioletMacrolanguage

Comment: Thankyou! This was the most simple and worked great.

Answer (score 0):

```
import random
def flatlist(l): return [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]

biglist = flatlist([[d]*people[d] for d in people])
print('weighted people:', biglist)

winner = random.choice(biglist)
print('winner:', winner)
```

Comment: Thankyou for this by the way. The comment above was more simple and worked as well. But you also taught me a few things in your comment. So thankyou for that