# Python dict of lists full join

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dict with list values, like this:

```
d = {'number': [1, 2], 'letter': ['a', 'b']}
```

I need to full join those lists, so I do:

```
keys = list(d.keys())

r = [
    {keys[0]: v1, keys[1]: v2}
    for v1 in d[keys[0]]
    for v2 in d[keys[1]]
]
```

This delivers the desired result:

```
[{'number': 1, 'letter': 'a'}, {'number': 1, 'letter': 'b'}, {'number': 2, 'letter': 'a'}, {'number': 2, 'letter': 'b'}]
```

How do I scale this solution for a case of 3 or more lists?
For example if I need to process a dict of 3 lists:

```
d = {'number': [1, 2], 'letter': ['a', 'b'], 'sign': ['!', '.']}
```

How to do this in case I don't know the number of lists inside the dict?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, use `itertools.product` like this:

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> d = {'number': [1, 2], 'letter': ['a', 'b']}
>>> [dict(zip(d, vs)) for vs in product(*d.values())]
[{'number': 1, 'letter': 'a'}, {'number': 1, 'letter': 'b'}, {'number': 2, 'letter': 'a'}, {'number': 2, 'letter': 'b'}]
```

Comment: Thanks! I actually needed a cartesian product, just didn't know what it is called.

Comment: is it guaranteed that zip(d, vs) will take dictionary items in the same order as product(*(d.values))? I mean, zip can take 'number' key first but product() will place letters first so we can end up with number keys paired with letters.

Comment: @prupru see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/835092/python-dictionary-are-keys-and-values-always-the-same-order)